# Phaser - How to check for sprite moving between two other sprites?

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm trying to check if one sprite is passing the line between two other sprites. I tried to check if the sprite is overlapping a Phaser.Line with:

```
this.lineGreenToRed = new Phaser.Line(this.ballGreen.x, this.ballGreen.y, this.ballRed.x, this.ballRed.y);

this.checkPassed = this.lineGreenToRed.pointOnLine(this.ballBlue.position.x, this.ballBlue.position.y);
if (this.checkPassed) {
    console.log('GreenToRed passed');
    //counter++;
};
console.log(this.checkPassed);
```

Looking into the console this counts up the false events whenever my sprite is not on/over the line. Moving it over the line sometimes gives me the true event, but not always. It looks like the frames change too fast to detect it. Overlap check on Lines does not seem to be possible neither.

I have also tried with:

```
this.GreenToRedArray = this.lineGreenToRed.coordinatesOnLine();
```

and in update():

```
this.GreenToRedArray.forEach(this.checkPoint, this);
```

and then:

```
checkPoint : function(element){
      if (this.ballBlue.position.x == element[0] && this.ballBlue.position.y == element[1]){
        console.log('GreenToRed passed');
        this.score++;
        console.log(this.score);
        this.scoreText.setText(this.score);
    }
},
```

This works as long as I move quite slow over the line, but as soon as things move a little faster, it does not catch it anymore.

Any hint on how I could check if one sprite is moving over the line between two other sprites?

Think of it as two balls marking kind of a goal and a third ball being shoot through between these two.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used `Phaser.Line`s too much, so after some research, and from what I've seen elsewhere, I might recommend going about this slightly differently.

One option would be changing the goal line to a `Phaser.Sprite` and then checking for [`overlap`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Sprite.html#overlap).

Alternatively, you could check for a rectangular intersection, as in the [Overlap Without Physics](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/overlap-without-physics) example.

```
function update() {
    if (checkOverlap(this.ballBlue, this.goal)) {
        console.log('overlapping');
    }
}
function checkOverlap(spriteA, spriteB) {
    var boundsA = spriteA.getBounds();
    var boundsB = spriteB.getBounds();

    return Phaser.Rectangle.intersects(boundsA, boundsB);
}
```

That could be tweaked so if you don't want to use a Sprite, you could use a `Phaser.Rectangle` instead of a `Phaser.Line`, changing the function accordingly.

I suppose you could also draw another `Phaser.Line` from the previous position of the ball to the current position, and check an intersection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help - my problem is that the "goal" is not fix. I have 3 balls in the game moving arround, bouncing from eachother and from the world boundaries. So the goal line/sprite/rectangle needs to be calculated every new round based in the distance and angle of the two balls acting as goal posts. This is also why drawing a second line from the previous position does not work: the ball might end up in a completely diferent position after passing the goal line (without intersection from its end position). Can I create a flexible sprite or rectangle somehow?

Comment: What I need is more like rectangle (or sprite) from x1, y1 to x2, y2 instead of the given recangle x, y, height, width. Any further hints/ideas would be most appreciated :-)

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I didn't realize that the two goal balls were moving as well. Digging deeper, it looks like [Phaser.Line.intersectsRectangle](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Line.html#.intersectsRectangle) might help. There's an example at http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/27412-line-collision/?do=findComment&comment=157389 Unlike `pointOnLine` which is just checking the anchor of the `Sprite`, this will test against the entire bounds of your ball sprite.

Comment: Great - thanks a lot, hopefully that works with my circle bodies as well - I'll try it next week... ...and might come back to it :-)

Comment: Woohoo! Glad to help :)